# Mock java.net.http.HttpClient responses using mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have a class that has two calls to `HttpClient.send` that I'd like to mock the responses for based on the request URI. I found some examples online but haven't been able to get them to work. One is:

```
HttpClient httpClient = mock(HttpClient.class);
when(httpClient.send(argThat(
    (HttpRequest httpRequest) -> httpRequest.uri().getHost().equals("http://localhost.com")), Mockito.any(HttpResponse.BodyHandler.class)))
    .thenReturn(mockedResponse);
```

but it's throwing the exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.net.http.HttpRequest.uri()" because "httpRequest" is null
```

Any ideas?

The following code is similar to what I am attempting to do:

```
class AuthenticationHandler {

  private HttpClient httpClient;
  private URI uriOne;
  private URI uriTwo;

  public AuthserviceAuthenticationHandler(HttpClient httpClient, URI uriOne, URI uriTwo) {
    this.httpClient = httpClient;
    this.uriOne = uriOne;
    this.uriTwo = uriTwo;
  }

  @Override
  protected void getTokenOne() {
    String tokenTwo = this.getTokenTwo();
    HttpRequest httpRequest;
    HttpResponse<String> httpResponse;
    httpRequest = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
          .uri(this.uriOne.resolve("/endpointAtUriOne"))
          .header("Authorization", "Basic %s".formatted(tokenTwo))
          .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString("Body"))
          .build();
    httpResponse = this.httpClient.send(httpRequest, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
    [...]
  }

    @Override
  private String getTokenTwo() {
    String token = null;
    HttpRequest httpRequest;
    HttpResponse<String> httpResponse;
    httpRequest = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
          .uri(this.uriTwo.resolve("/endpointAtUriTwo"))
          .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString("Body"))
          .build();
    httpResponse = this.httpClient.send(httpRequest, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
    // Parse response, return token string.
    return token;
  }
```

In my test, I create a mock `HttpClient`, which is passed to the constructor, but I am not sure how to have the mocked client return a different response based on the request object URI.

Comment: Can you add the code which creates the request and calls send?

Comment: Can you post the code that sends the get request?

Comment: More detailed code example was just added.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that -- you'll need to produce a complete example which fails.